What papers or books should I read in order?
I have been reading literature on modal set theory and am currently reading Putnam's "Mathematics Without Foundations," which is known for being one of the earliest presentations of this concept.
I understand that Putnam's belief that sentences like the Continuum Hypothesis have truth values is influenced by a Platonic view of sets, which sees the concept of sets as realistic. To avoid a realist perspective, I understand that his intention to reinterpret set-theoretical sentences as modal sentences to bypass this issue to some extent.
However, from the next section " significance of antinomies",
I start to struggle with understanding the translation set-theoretical sentences to modal language.
He understands a model of set theory through an analogy of a graph, but I cannot understand the intention behind this analogy. While I agree that a model can be understood as a set of symbols and sentences with specific conditions, thus can be seen as a specific set, I don't understand why he uses this analogy. This confusion likely stems from my lack of understanding of model theory. But, since I ultimately want to learn about modal set theory, I would appreciate it if you could suggest a study order.
To summarize, (1) what does Putnam mean by stating that a model can be viewed as a graph, and why does he make such a claim?
(2) And I would appreciate it if you could suggest some books or articles to study in sequence. I have a basic understanding of modal logic and have a sub-major in mathematics. I've also self-studied textbooks on model theory, but I still consider myself almost a novice.

Philosophy of Mathematics with bibliography and many related entries.

The "graph-model" is a description of Von Neumann universe.

You can see also Øystein Linnebo, Putnam on Mathematics as Modal Logic, into Geoffrey Hellmann & Roy Cook (editors), Hilary Putnam on logic and mathematics (Springer, 2018).
